# ElasticSearch - Aggregation result not matching total hits

Tags: elasticsearch

I have query like below. It returns 320 results for the below condition-

```
{
    "size": "5000",
    "sort": [
        {
            "errorDateTime": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "errorDateTime": {
                            "gte": "2021-04-07T20:08:20.516",
                            "lte": "2021-04-08T00:08:20.516"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "businessFunction": "PriceUpdate"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "businessFunction": "PriceFeedIntegration"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "businessFunction": "StoreConnectivity"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "businessFunction": "Transaction"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "businessFunction": "SalesSummary"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "genres_and_store": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "storeId"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "genres_and_error": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "errorCode"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "genres_and_business": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "businessFunction"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However the aggregation results are not matching. I have so many stores which are not returned in aggregation but I can see them in query result. What am I missing? My schema looks like -

```
{
                    "errorDescription": "FTP Service unable to connect to Store to list the files for Store 12345",
                    "errorDateTime": "2021-04-07T21:01:15.040546",
                    "readBy": [],
                    "errorCode": "e004",
                    "businessFunction": "TransactionError",
                    "storeId": "12345"
                }
```

Please let me know if I am writing the query wrong. I want to aggregare per store, per errorcode and per businessFunction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If no `size` param is set in the terms aggregation, then by default it returns the top 10 terms, which are ordered by their `doc_count`. You need to add the [`size`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size) param in the terms aggregation, to get all the matching total hits.**

Try out the below query

```
{
  "size": "5000",
  "sort": [
    {
      "errorDateTime": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "errorDateTime": {
              "gte": "2021-04-07T20:08:20.516",
              "lte": "2021-04-08T00:08:20.516"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "businessFunction": "PriceUpdate"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "businessFunction": "PriceFeedIntegration"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "businessFunction": "StoreConnectivity"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "businessFunction": "Transaction"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "businessFunction": "SalesSummary"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "genres_and_store": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "storeId",
        "size": 100               // note this
      },
      "aggs": {
        "genres_and_error": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "errorCode"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "genres_and_business": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "businessFunction"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think I was missing size parameter inside aggs and was getting default 10 aggregations only:

```
"aggs": {
        "genres_and_store": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "storeId",
                "size": 1000
            },
```

Comment: same answer as above